# How to delete a certain row from my mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a school closings system with a database so that we don't have to put all the schools in manually every time we need to update it.

What I am wanting to do is have all the schools in the database but only show schools that have a status other then Open. So for example, if School 1 is Open but School 2 is cancelled I only want to show School 2.

I would also like to be able to show a message of all schools are set to Open in the status column.

```
<html>
<?php

//make connection to database
mysql_connect('***', '***', '***');

//select database
mysql_select_db('***');

$sql="SELECT * FROM Schools";

$records=mysql_query($sql);

?>

<head>
<title>School Closings</title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="600px" border="1px" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="3px">
<tr>

<th>Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>

<?php

while($Schools=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>".$Schools['Name']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$Schools['Status']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$Schools['Comments']."</td>";

echo "</tr>";

}//end while

?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't know your table structure.  Please change accordingly your `$sql`.  `SELECT * FROM Schools where status != 'Open'`

Comment: sigh, stop using mysql_* thanks

Comment: as @dagon said, get off the mysql_* library. Plenty of reasons, and as you are just starting out, no better time. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info

Comment: Roullie - This is the code I was looking for. This is doing exactly what I want. Is there a way to show a message if all the schools are set to a status of Open?

Answer (score 2):

**$sql=SELECT * FROM schools WHERE status = 'Cancelled';**
Use this query, you don't need to delete the records, this query will fetch the records of **schools that are not open or cancelled**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to delete any rows at all.  I think you want to DISPLAY only certain rows, and exclude others from being displayed.  In accordance with this assumption:

Just modify the query to include a `where` clause that selects only results with the status 'closed' (or however you flag this status):

```
SELECT name, status, comments FROM schools WHERE status <> 'open';
```

Or 
    `WHERE closed = 1;`

whatever the case may be (depending of course on your table structure)

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to accomplish however I just want to filer out the schools that have a status of open. While we will use a status that says closed, we will also have other ones that include 2 Hours Late, Closed, and Alert. Is there just a way for the script to look for the word Open in the code and display records that say anything but that?

Comment: Yep. Use where status <> "open"

Comment: <> means "does not equal"

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `WHERE` clause in your query to filter the `status`.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Schools WHERE `status` = 'cancelled'";
```

and don't use the * in SELECT statement, specify the column names in your code !

Comment: why not to use `SELECT *`??

Comment: @user3284463 If we use SELECT * , it will retrieve all the columns from the table. Its good to practice with specifying the column names while using SELECT statement. It will be useful while handling with large tables !

Comment: But if you want all the columns, then can you use `SELECT *`? . You phrased it wrong in your answer. Try typing answers that are quality and explain why not to do this and that in your ANSWER and avoid getting down voted. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @user3284463 where did i phrased WRONG ? first understand the statement ! and i just posted my view on this. Not for getting votes !